# Sass dynamic function depending on the root class

Tags: css, sass

I have an app which is being displayed in 3 modes regardless of scaling and pixel count:

- 16x9,
- 16x9 - 1/4 of screen space, so 1/2 w, 1/2 h. Rest is filled with
  other content.
- 9x16

The mode is inferred from an external settings api, and is set via an id attr on one of the main nodes.

I have a helper function to calculate the relative units for the main 16x9 mode:

```
@function ru($value) {
  $value: calc($value / 1px);
  $target: calc($value / 1920 * 10000);

  @return calc(round($target) / 100 * 1vw);
}
```

usage:

```
.container {
  width: ru(200px);
}
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to dynamically adjust the function depending on the root id attr eg:

```
$width: 1920;

#mode2 {
  $width: 3840;
}

#mode3 {
  $width: 1080;
}

@function ru($value) {
  $value: calc($value / 1px);
  $target: calc($value / $width * 10000);

  @return calc(round($target) / 100 * 1vw);
}
```

I know I can drop sass variables for plain css ones and it would work

```
body {
  --width: 1920;
}

#mode2 {
  --width: 3840;
}

#mode3 {
  --width: 1080;
}

@function ru($value) {
  $value: calc($value / 1px);
  $target: calc($value / var(--width));

  @return calc($target * 1vw);
}
```

but that means I have to drop the rounds,
and I'm uncertain on the performance scaling **(I have no idea what I'm taking about)**
but I'd assume the precompiled sass values would be better than calc statements all over the app.

I'm also using modules, and have to manually import the helper file in each of those

**In conclusion:**

I'd like to know if it's possible to write the sass function which would compute different values depending on the root id attr, which I assume is no, since it's precompiled.

Perhaps some sort of mixin is possible, where it could generate the values for all 3 cases?

input:

```
.container {
  width: ru(200px);
  ...other styles
}
```

output:

```
.container {
  width: 10vw;
  ...other styles
}

#mode2 .container {
  width: 5vw;
}

#mode3 .container {
  width: 17.77vw;
}
```

Comment: as you mentioned, it's precompiled.
so you can't calculate on the fly.
on the other hand, I got that you need to set a dynamic ratio.
based on a changing height or may be a pregiven height in percentage or vh, and that is applicable in css.